# writing file comparison in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am comparing columns in 2 files and writing the result to a third file if value in file 1 col1 == value in file2 col2. I wish to use pandas instead.

My code:

```
f1 = open( 'f1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open( 'f2.txt', 'r')
f3 = open( 'f3.txt', 'w+')
for row1 in f1:
    f1_row = row1.strip('\n').split(' ')
    for row2 in f2:
        f2_row = row2.strip('\n').split(' ')
        if f1_row[0] == f2_row[0]
            f3.write('\t'.join(f2_row)
    f2.seek(0,0)
f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

Example files and results

```
file 1
     1 3 5 6
     3 8 9 0
     4 5 7 1
     2 6 7 9

file 2
 0 5 6 7 9 9 1
 3 4 5 6 7 7 4
 2 8 7 9 3 2 0
 1 0 3 3 4 6 7
 7 8 3 9 1 1 2

result
 1 0 3 3 4 6 7
 3 4 5 6 7 7 4
 2 8 7 9 3 2 0
```

How do I generate this in pandas? Thank you

Comment: Elaborate in terms of what? What I have now works but I want another way of writing this and using pandas seem like the best way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `pandas`

```
df1=pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

result=df1[[1]].merge(df2,how='inner')
Out[236]: 
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
0  1  0  3  3  4  6  7
1  3  4  5  6  7  7  4
2  2  8  7  9  3  2  0


result.to_csv('fil3.csv')
```

Comment: How do you get the returned rows to follow the order in column 1 of file 1 like in my result. This seem to follow the order in file2